# Python integrate.quad(1/function) error

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I have the following existing code:

```
integrate.quad(somefunc, lowerbound, upperbound)
```

However I want to change this to

```
integrate.quad(1/somefunc, lowerbound, upperbound)
```

but I get operand errors. Is there a way I can do this without changing somefunc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a lambda to call the function appropriately, similar to so:

```
integrate.quad(lambda x: 1/somefunc(x), lowerbound, upperbound)
```